# How can I build a report that will show what business unit(s) all Marketing Cloud users belong to?

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration, system-admin

I am trying to build a comprehensive list of which marketing cloud users have access to which business units without having to going into each user's "manage business units" section and check person by person. We are moving to a multi-org setup and need to link each user dependent on associated business units. Ideally this would include the username and enabled/disabled, broken down by each business unit. Bonus points if you know a way to easily look back to their Salesforce Sales Cloud username as well. Does anyone know of a potential solution in Marketing Cloud's reporting functionality that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the SOAP API, you can retrieve the users associated to a business unit, through the [BusinessUnit Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/businessunit.htm)

> AccountUsers   AccountUser[]   An array of users associated with a specific account.